# Finding the Bootstrap variable that controls a specific CSS rule

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm developing an application using Bootstrap 3. I use Sass/SCSS to customize the Bootstrap variables neatly.

I'm currently styling the "tabs" component and I can't seem to figure out *if* there is a specific variable that controls its text color, or if it's been inherited from somewhere else.

What's a good way to determine the "source" of a CSS rule that comes from Bootstrap? I use Chrome on OSX.

Comment: Search for the CSS class that is applied to the _tab_ and search for it in the SCSS files.

Comment: @hungerstar: That's what I'm doing now and it's becoming a very inefficient workday for me...

Comment: What is the actual name of the component you are working on in Bootstrap 3? _"tabs"_ doesn't help a whole lot.

Comment: @hungerstar: It's part of "navs": http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected the tab on the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs) and searched for the `.nav-tabs` class in the bootstrap scss files. So in the [_navs.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navs.scss) file, search for "tabs" and you'll see the variables.

It looks like `$nav-tabs-active-link-hover-color` might be what you're looking for - it's the active tab's text color. The anchors in the non-active tabs appear to be default anchor tag color.

You can find that variable in the [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) file. The variables are usually named according to the component that uses them (i.e. `$nav-tabs-active-<whatever>`).

```
  // Active state, and its :hover to override normal :hover
    &.active > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-color; // ****** here
        background-color: $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-bg;
        border: 1px solid $nav-tabs-active-link-hover-border-color;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        cursor: default;
      }
    }
```